# prevent focus out for a QWidget

Tags: c++, qt

I'd like to write a `QDialog` lookalike class. I've managed to filter out mouse events to non-dialog widgets pretty well, but I still have a problem with focus. As the `QDialog` lookalike class is just a usual widget it can lose focus by way of key presses (tabs). Hence widgets not related to the `QDialog` lookalive, that I cannot click, but are focus-able, may get the focus. Is there a neat way to prevent the user from focusing away from my dialog lookalike's child widgets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
// somewhere in your code
connect(qApp, SIGNAL(focusChanged(QWidget*,QWidget*)),
  SLOT(focusChanged(QWidget*,QWidget*)));

void MyDialog::focusChanged(QWidget*, QWidget* to)
{
  if (!isAncestorOf(to))
  {
    QWidget* widget(qobject_cast<QWidget*>(children().front()));

    widget->setFocus(Qt::OtherFocusReason);

    QKeyEvent event(QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_Tab, Qt::NoModifier);

    qApp->sendEvent(widget, &event);
  }
  // else do nothing
}
```

Assuming the child is an instance of `QFrame` or `QWidget`.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that your QDialog-like widget is an individual window, I think you are looking for `QWdiget::setModal( true )`. It prevents widgets in other windows of your application to receive any input events.

Comment: True, but the window needs to be top-level (parent = 0). Mine explicitly must not be. That's because under linux, it is possible to move other application top-level windows around and I want to prevent that.

Comment: Is it then possible to install an event filter to all other windows? This could even allow you to automatically bring your dialog back to front if the user tries to interact with any of the other windows.

Comment: I've solved the "bringing to the front part", an event filter is exactly what I am trying to avoid, especially an application-wide one. Some controls, such as QTableView don't allow the focus to leave them via the tab key, I'll go source diving to find out how.